# Trying to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE with rollback

Tags: jdbc, greenplum

I am building a Java program that needs to automatically collect data on SQL statements before scheduling them. The program right now runs an `EXPLAIN` statement and parses the results.

I need the time parameter, so I need to run with `ANALYZE`, but I don't want to affect any data, so I need to rollback. When I attempt to run this all as one block, as suggested in the PostgreSQL documentation, with:

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE ...(statement)
ROLLBACK;
```

I don't get the results of the `EXPLAIN` statement, rather I get that this block of queries didn't affect any rows.

So I am not sure of the best way to get this data. My thought is perhaps to build a function where the statement is a `text` argument and that returns a table that's just 1 row/column containing the `EXPLAIN` output, but I'm not really a PostgreSQL function wiz so a simpler alternative is preferable.

Not really sure how to go about this. Any assistance would be helpful!

Comment: You're likely getting *both* the update count from the statement *and* the explain plan results, so you need to call [`stmt.getMoreResults()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--) to get it all.

Comment: Please show the code used.

Comment: did you try to disable autocommit on the connection, then only send the `explain...` using `execute()` and do the rollback using `Connection.rollback()`?

Comment: Actually using a Greenplum server, so it was forked after 8.2. Let me see about the autocommit setting, I'm using the java.sql.DriverManager library, and the getConnection method with 
  .use { connection ->
            connection.prepareStatement(query).also { preparedStatement ->
                preparedStatement.executeQuery().also { resultSet ->
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        results.add(resultSet.getString(1))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Please **edit** your question, don't post pertinent information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you are running the statements “as one block”, you probably mean that you are running the three statements in one `java.sql.Statement.execute()`.

Then you will only see the result set from the last statement, which happens to be `ROLLBACK`.

Rather, you should do it like this:

```java
conn.setAutocommit(false);
java.sql.Resultset rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("EXPLAIN ...");
// retrieve the EXPLAIN result
conn.rollback();
```